# How do I loop one input instead of restarting the entire program?

Tags: python

I have a simple ice cream program, everything works. But how do I loop a single input like scoops if the input is invalid? Currently if the input is incorrect it re-asks the user for the first input again. Meaning if I enter vanilla for the flavor and 7 for the number of scoops, it will print the error message, then instead of re-asking how many scoops you'd like, it asks you what flavor you'd like. How would I fix this for my three inputs throughout the program? I would still like the program to restart after a valid order is entered. Thank you for your time.

Program code:

```
#Error for wrong flavor selection
class FlavorError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, flavors, message):
        Exception.__init__(self, flavors, message)
        self.flavors = flavors

#Error for wrong number of scoops selection
class ScoopsError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, scoops, message):
        Exception.__init__(self, scoops, message)
        self.scoops = scoops

#Error for wrong carrier selection
class HoldingsError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, holdings, message):
        Exception.__init__(self, holdings, message)
        self.holdings = holdings


def main():
    #Creating Values
    flavors= " "
    scoops = " "
    holdings = " "
    while True:
        try:
            #MENU / INFORMATION
            print("Flavors: vanilla, chocolate, strawberry, mint, pistachio, and spumoni")
            print("Number of scoops: 1, 2, 3")
            print("Ways to eat: bowl or cone")
            print()
            #FLAVOR INPUT
            flavors = input("Enter a flavor of ice cream: ").lower()
            print()
            #ERROR CHECK
            if flavors not in ['vanilla', 'chocolate', 'strawberry', 'mint', 'pistachio', 'spumoni']:
                raise FlavorError(flavors, "is not on the menu.")
            #NUMBER OF SCOOPS INPUT
            scoops = int(input("Enter the number of scoops: "))
            print()
            #ERROR CHECK
            if scoops > 3 or scoops <= 0:
                raise ScoopsError(scoops, 'We do not offer that many scoops!')
            #CARRIER INPUT
            holdings = input("Would you like a cone or bowl? ")
            print()
            #ERROR CHECK
            if holdings not in ['bowl', 'cone']:
                raise HoldingsError(holdings, 'Please select between a bowl or a cone')
            print(scoops , "scoops of" , flavors , "in a" , holdings)
            print()
        except Exception as e:
            print("Invalid choice! try again!"+str(e))
            print()

main()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you clarify on what you mean by `restarts the entire program`? Does the program error out? Thanks!

Comment: First of all, you don't necessarily need to raise an exception for the wrong number of scoops. Just a message and a new prompt will suffice.

Comment: I just editted my post, I hope it is more clear.

Comment: In your own words, how are you deciding which lines of your program should be within your `while` loop and which should not? In your own words, how do you signal to Python which lines are within the `while` loop and which are not? In your own words, what lines should go inside a loop in order to get the behaviour you want? So, just put it together. This is not really a programming question, it's a reasoning question; and the best way to get through it is to practice doing the reasoning yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, but I believe this will work for you and you are already using similar logic for your flavors.

If you need more complexity, the link at the top is what you want.

```
while scoops not in [1,2,3]:
    scoops = int(input("Enter the number of scoops: "))
```

Comment: thank you works great

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the required behavior you may surround  each input with while loop.

and break the loop only if the input is valid so it will continue executing the program